# convert large binary file to hexadecimal (binascii.hexlify returns MemoryError)

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a large file (~1GB) into hexadecimal string with binascii (which works great on smaller files), but it causing a MemoryError.

this is the code I am using:

```
import binascii

filePath = "demo/11.mp4.zip"

file = open(filePath, "rb")
with file:
    byte = file.read()
    hexa = binascii.hexlify(byte)

hexa_string = hexa.decode('ascii');
```

any advice?

Comment: What do you want to do with the result (hex string)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read your file in chucks:

```
import binascii

file_path = 'demo/11.mp4.zip'

chunk_size = 1024
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        hexa = binascii.hexlify(data)
        hexa_string = hexa.decode('ascii')
        # work with hex string
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually You are approximately using 3 GB of your memory with storing the file and its hex within `byte` and `hexa` variables, instead of that you can iterate within your file and process the it based on chunks .

Comment: It is a 3 GB minimum (a single byte translates to 2 hex digits). There is no point to read a **zip** file (binary) of `mp4` file (binary) line by line. You might mean that a file could be read in chunks instead of all at once